# how to get balance of buy and sell when there are different currency?

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following MySQL table containing buy and sell with associated amounts of different  currency, how to select total sum of buy,sell and balance according to each `currency`? I have tried but something isn't working correctly.

```
id      currency    buy  change_Currency     sell
1         USD      1000        DR             3670             
2         EURO      100        USD            130
3         DR        500        USD            136
4         USD       500        EURO           600
5         USD       1200        DR            3800
```

My MySQL query that doesn't work:

SELECT `currency`,SUM(`buy`)-SUM(`sell`) AS balance FROM deal GROUP BY `currency`,`change_currency`

The result I want is something like:

```
currency    buy     sell    balance
  USD       2700    266      2434 
  DR        500     7470     -6970      
 EURO       100     600      -500
```

I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Group twice the table, once for buys and for sales and then join the results:

```
select 
  t1.currency,
  t1.total buy,
  t2.total sell,
  t1.total - t2.total balance
from (
  select currency, sum(buy) total from deal
  group by currency 
) t1 inner join (
  select change_currency, sum(sell) total from deal
  group by change_currency 
) t2 on t2.change_currency = t1.currency
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sCZNRkNs5h2ZTHfg5KqyGa/0).
Results:

```
| currency | buy  | sell | balance |
| -------- | ---- | ---- | ------- |
| DR       | 500  | 7470 | -6970   |
| EURO     | 100  | 600  | -500    |
| USD      | 2700 | 266  | 2434    |
```

Comment: thank you , your answer is correct. i want to use condition in where class like (where date = '7/28/2019') how i add this condition in your answer.@forpas

Answer (score 2):

Use self join and `sum()` Aggregation grouping only by currency :

```
select t1.currency, 
       sum(t1.buy) as buy,
       sum(t2.sell) as sell,
       sum(t1.buy)-sum(t2.sell) as balance
  from ( select currency, sum(buy) as buy from deal group by currency ) t1
  join ( select change_Currency, sum(sell) as sell from deal group by change_Currency ) t2 
    on t1.Currency=t2.change_Currency
 group by t1.currency
```

Comment: INNER JOIN can lead to row exclusion if a currency is missing in one of the subqueries.

Comment: sure @PaulSpiegel, but I preferred because of being enough for this sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `union all` and aggregation.  You can do aggregation *before* and *after* the `union all`:

```
select currency, sum(buy), sum(sell),
       sum(buy) - sum(sell)
from ((select currency, sum(buy) as buy, 0 as sell
       from deal
       group by currency
      ) union all
      (select change_currency, 0, sum(sell) as sell
       from deal
       group by change_currency
      )
     ) bs
group by currency;
```

If you have a separate table of currencies, then the most efficient method might be correlated subqueries:

```
select c.currency,
       (select sum(d.buy)
        from deal d
        where d.currency = c.currency
       ) as buy,
       (select sum(d.sell)
        from deal d
        where d.change_currency = c.currency
       ) as sell
from currencies c;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of indexes on `deal(currency, buy)` and `deal(change_currency, sell)`.

Comment: This is more accurate than the answers with INNER JOIN, since they can exclude a currency which has only been either bought or sold.

Comment: thank you , your answer is correct. i want to use condition in where class like (where date = '7/28/2019') how i add this condition in your first answer.

Comment: @safiullah . . . For the first, add it twice, before the `group by`s in the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `UNION` and a sub query to get both columns specifying currency into the same column. The syntax might be slightly off for mysql as I haven't used it in years.

```
SELECT currency, sum(buy), sum(sell), sum(buy) - sum(sell) balance FROM 
    (SELECT currency, buy, 0 sell FROM deal
     UNION 
     SELECT change_currency, 0, sell FROM deal) deals
GROUP BY currency
ORDER BY currency
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something like this

```sql
SELECT
deal1.currency
, sum(deal1.buy) as buy
, sum(deal2.sell) as sell
, (sum(deal1.buy) - sum(deal2.sell)) as balance
FROM deal deal1
join deal deal2
  on deal1.currency = deal2.change_Currency
GROUP BY deal1.currency
```

Comment: You can't simply group of currency as the sell currency is specified by `change_currency`. The balances will mix them up.